# I am continuously getting this problem when I run the command npm run watch. Any idea of what to do?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, npm, web-deployment

I am trying to run `npm run watch` But it always returns the below error:

````
>```none
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors2:50:28 PM
>
This dependency was not found:
>
* vue in ./resources/js/app.js
>
To install it, you can run: npm install --save vue
<s> [webpack.Progress] 100%
>
       Asset      Size   Chunks             Chunk Names
/css/app.css   178 KiB  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app
  /js/app.js  1.08 MiB  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app
>
ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\resources\js'
 @ ./resources/js/app.js 8:13-27
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys'
>```
````

How can I fix this? Any idea?

Comment: Did you run `npm install`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you used `vue` in your code but never installed it.

What the error is telling you is to install `vue` using `npm install --save vue`. After the installation you can try to do `npm run watch` again

Answer (score 0):

Simply run `npm i` to install all dependencies.
Then run `npm run watch`